# Grails Proxy Authentication Error

Tags: authentication, grails, proxy

I am running behind Corporate Proxy.
Using latest version of Grails 2.4.4. When trying to create a new Grails project in STS, I am getting the following error:

> Loading Grails 2.4.4 |Configuring classpath Error | [main] WARN
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication - NEGOTIATE
>   authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level:
>   No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any
>   Kerberos tgt)) Error | [main] WARN
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication - NEGOTIATE
>   authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level:
>   No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any
>   Kerberos tgt))

I have already set http proxy correctly in ProxySettings.groovy using the command add-proxy and set-proxy. But still no luck in running the grails app.

Please help.

Comment: Likely this unresolved bug?: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11628

Comment: Has anyone been able to run a grails app using STS IDE behind Proxy Firewall successfully ? If so, please provide the steps involved. Which versions of grails, STS do not have the above known bug ? I am keen on learning grails framework, but am stuck at this very first step here. I believe there should be some workaround for this? Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally some relief. Downloaded older version of GGTS (Groovy/Grails Tool Suite) having Grails v 2.0.4 bundled. Now everything seems to be working smoothly.

Guys, as mentioned above, the latest version of Grails has the above mentioned bug starting from v 2.3.8 onwards which is still unresolved till the current version 2.4.4.

If you are looking for an easy workaround, please download the older version of STS and Grails 2.0.4 for developing applications. Here is the download [link](http://download.springsource.com/milestone/STS/3.0.0.M3/dist/e4.2/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.0.0.M3-e4.2-win32.zip).

Answer (score 0):

I got around this problem by changing the dependency resolution engine from maven to ivy with following line in

```
BuildConfig.groovy:
    grails.project.dependency.resolver = 'ivy'
```